# Original master fails to join maxscale as slave once he is back up

Tags: mariadb, replication, maxscale

In my projecto i am using docker compose to run an api (using tomcat). That api connect to a maxscale server that "connects" to other 3 databases (1 master and 2 slaves).

I've enabled replication on the mariadb side and it is recognized on the maxscale UI.

[image]

If i shut down my master one of the slaves gets promoted to a new master (the expected result). The problem comes when i turn my original master back on i get the following error:

```
db   | 2023-07-07  6:58:11 5 [ERROR] Slave I/O: Fatal error: The slave I/O thread stops because master and slave have equal MariaDB server ids;
these ids must be different for replication to work (or the --replicate-same-server-id option must be used on slave but this does not always make sense; please check the manual before using it).
Internal MariaDB error code: 1593
```

**The strange part is the fact that if I turn of the slave that was promoted to master and turn him back on he joins as a slave again no problem at all.**

Docker compose file:

```
#Use docker compose up --build to run. Without the build we might have problems connecting to the db

version: '3'
#use this volumes if i want to use the same volume in multiple services
#then we call data:path/ in the services to use this volume
volumes:
  data:
services:
  #Database container
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: root
      #Password for my root user
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
    #Copies the init.sql file that has all the initializations for the docker entry point to create the tables
    volumes:
      - ./Database/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - ./Database/initSlaves.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initSlaves.sql
    
    #Maps my computers 50000 port to the 3306 on the container. Now i can access the database using localhost:50000
    #Port 50000 gets exposed to my machine but not other images
    ports:
      - "50000:3306"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/local/bin/healthcheck.sh", "--connect", "--innodb_initialized"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
    command:
      - '--log-bin'
      - '--server-id=3001'
      - '--log-basename=my_logs'
      - '--log-slave-updates'

      
  db2:
    container_name: db2
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: root
      #Password for my root user
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
    #Copies the init.sql file that has all the initializations for the docker entry point to create the tables
    volumes:
      - ./Database/initSlaves.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initSlaves.sql
    
    #Maps my computers 50000 port to the 3306 on the container. Now i can access the database using localhost:50000
    #Port 50000 gets exposed to my machine but not other images
    ports:
      - "50010:3306"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/local/bin/healthcheck.sh", "--connect", "--innodb_initialized"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: false
    command:
      - '--log-bin'
      - '--server-id=3002'
      - '--log-basename=my_logs'
      - '--log-slave-updates'
    

  db3:
    container_name: db3
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: root
      #Password for my root user
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
    #Copies the init.sql file that has all the initializations for the docker entry point to create the tables
    volumes:
      - ./Database/initSlaves.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initSlaves.sql
    
    #Maps my computers 50000 port to the 3306 on the container. Now i can access the database using localhost:50000
    #Port 50000 gets exposed to my machine but not other images
    ports:
      - "50020:3306"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/local/bin/healthcheck.sh", "--connect", "--innodb_initialized"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: false
    command:
      - '--log-bin'
      - '--server-id=3003'
      - '--log-basename=my_logs'
      - '--log-slave-updates'
    
  #Need tomcat to host the api
  api:
    container_name: api
    image: tomcat
    #will place my jar/war file inside the webapps folder
    volumes:
      - ./api/target/api.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/api.war
    #use localhost:50001 to access tomcat
    #but in the url for the database i have to use port 3306 (since that one is visible to my docker image)
    ports:
      - "50001:8080"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: false
      db2:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: false
      db3:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: false
  maxscale:
    image: mariadb/maxscale
    container_name: max
    ports:
      - "4006:4006" 
      - "4008:4008"
      - "50002:8989"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: maxscale
      #Password for my root user
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: maxscale
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: false
      db2:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: false
      db3:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: false
    volumes:
      - ./maxscale/maxscale.cnf:/etc/maxscale.cnf.d/my-maxscale.cnf
```

init.sql

```
CREATE USER 'maxscale'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'maxscale';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'maxscale'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'maxscale' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'maxscale'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'repluser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repluser'@'%';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

CREATE SCHEMA mydb;

use mydb;

CREATE  TABLE user ( 
    id                 INT  NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
    email              VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL     ,
    password           VARCHAR(512)  NOT NULL     ,
    name               VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL     ,
    age                INT  NOT NULL     ,
    UNIQUE             (email)
 ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE friends ( 
    userId             INT  NOT NULL     ,
    friendId           INT  NOT NULL     ,
    date               DATETIME  NOT NULL     ,
    CONSTRAINT pk_friends PRIMARY KEY ( UserId, FriendId )
 ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX friendId_idx ON friends ( userId  ASC, friendId  ASC ) VISIBLE;

CREATE  TABLE posts ( 
    userId             INT  NOT NULL     ,
    date               DATETIME  NOT NULL     ,
    text               VARCHAR(512)       ,
    image              MEDIUMBLOB       ,
    CONSTRAINT pk_posts PRIMARY KEY ( UserId, Date )
 ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE posts ADD CONSTRAINT FK_UserId FOREIGN KEY ( userId ) REFERENCES user( id ) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE friends ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FriendId_User FOREIGN KEY ( userId ) REFERENCES user( id ) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE friends ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FriendId_Friend FOREIGN KEY ( friendId ) REFERENCES user( id ) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

INSERT INTO user (email,password,name,age) VALUES ("admin@admin.com","123456","Admin",31);

INSERT INTO user (email,password,name,age) VALUES ("user1@user.com","123456","user1",31);
INSERT INTO user (email,password,name,age) VALUES ("user2@user.com","123456","user2",31);
INSERT INTO user (email,password,name,age) VALUES ("user3@user.com","123456","user3",31);

INSERT INTO posts (userId,date,text,image) VALUES (2,now(),"Hello world",NULL);
DO SLEEP(3);
INSERT INTO posts (userId,date,text,image) VALUES (2,now(),"Hello world 2",NULL);
INSERT INTO posts (userId,date,text,image) VALUES (3,now(),"Hello world 3",NULL);

INSERT INTO friends (userId,friendId,date) VALUES (2,3,now());
INSERT INTO friends (userId,friendId,date) VALUES (2,4,now());
```

initSlaves.sql

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
  MASTER_HOST='db',
  MASTER_USER='repluser',
  MASTER_PASSWORD='123456',
  MASTER_PORT=3306,
  MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY=10;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Ps: I've tried checking the server id on the main master server and he has 3001 while the slaves have 3002 and 3003.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Docker Official images now have [MARIADB_MASTER_HOST](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-server-docker-official-image-environment-variables/#mariadb_master_host) (for replica), and [MARIADB_REPLICATION_USER / MARIADB_REPLICATION_PASSWORD](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-server-docker-official-image-environment-variables/#mariadb_replication_user-mariadb_replication_password_hash-mariadb_replication_password) (on all) to make the initialization of replication easier.

Comment: Oh, and [healthcheck.sh](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-healthcheck-sh-script/) has `--replication` as a health check.

Comment: @danblack I changed the code to use those env vars but the problem it still happens. Db cant join after it goes down. But db2 and db3 can join over and over, going from masters to slaves just fine :s

Comment: Ack. I didn't expect to fix it, just saw it as an easier form to what you have. Evidently I need to add a GTID option too. Also no need for `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`, not needed for `CHANGE MASTER` or any `CREATE USER` / `GRANT`/ etc. Its horrendously overused when not needed.

Answer (score 1):

For failover in MaxScale to work, [you should be using GTID replication](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-2302-mariadb-monitor/#limitations-and-requirements):

> The backends must all use GTID-based replication, and the domain id should not change during a switchover or failover. Primary and replicas must have well-behaving GTIDs with no extra events on replica servers.

Comment: I am usin it, at least in the two slaves, because they work flawlessly. The problem is the master that cant join as a slave once he is back up. On the other hand a slave can become a master and leave and rejoin as a slave any time, for db2 and db3 it is working great.

Comment: The configurations of all the nodes should be mostly identical except for `server_id` which must be unique. Are there some parameters that aren't set on the master that are on the slave servers?

Comment: No, all parameters look the same in all databases. The only difference is that i run an sql file to initialize the database and create a new users.